# Why I can't insert Youtube video into Whatsapp chat?

Tags: video, youtube, whatsapp, web-whatsapp

Usually I copied and pasted Youtube link into Whatsapp chat and the link automatically converted to embedded video. But since November 27 2020 this does not work for me. So I can paste the link but it stays as link and is not being converted into embedded video.

I thought that it is a bug of Android application, but I tried the same thing in Whatsapp Web and I got the same result.
Some of my friends have the same problem since November 27, but others can insert Youtube videos without any issues.

How to solve the problem?

Comment: Maybe the person who posted the vídeo didn't choose the option to allow video to be embedded...

Comment: Both Youtube and WhatsApp can be used as web apps, and given that the problem exists there, this is really a question for the WebApps stackechange site. Either its a bug or a new feature change in WhatsApp, but in any case, its outside of the scope of SuperUser.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may now only be able to do it from the youtube app -> share -> whatsapp

Here is what I found on it [https://www.indiatoday.in/information/story/how-to-share-youtube-links-on-whatsapp-status-step-by-step-guide-1669701-2020-04-22#:~:text=Step%201%3A%20Open%20YouTube%20on,and%20then%20Share%20on%20Status](https://www.indiatoday.in/information/story/how-to-share-youtube-links-on-whatsapp-status-step-by-step-guide-1669701-2020-04-22#:%7E:text=Step%201%3A%20Open%20YouTube%20on,and%20then%20Share%20on%20Status).

Thanks,

Mike